# Pass function parameter in pipe

Tags: bash, function, awk, pipe, parameter-passing

I wrote a function inside a bash script with some help:

```
function test() {
    temp=$(cat /etc/passwd | grep $(whoami) | awk -F : "{print $`echo $1`}")
    echo "$temp"
}
```

I give it a number X and it should print the Xth column from the users entry in the passwd file.

```
echo $(test "3")
```

...will give me the entry of the third column.
I have trouble understanding how the awk part works. How does the echo part in

```
"{print $`echo $1`}"
```

access the functions `$1` and not the `$1` from the pipe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing up awk and shell and misunderstanding what awk is for plus some shell fundamentals and so creating a complicated mess. All you need is:

```
mytest() {
    awk -F':' -v col="$1" -v me="$(whoami)" '$1==me{print $col}' /etc/passwd
}

mytest 3
```

I renamed the function "test" to "mytest" since "test" is the name of a shell builtin.

Get the books Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins and Shell Scripting Recipes by Chris Johnson.

Comment: I tried to combine a few new things I'm learning at the moment. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: You're welcome. Be careful where you're learning from as online scripts and tutorials are 95% nonsense. Whatever you read that led to the shell and awk scripts you created - delete those bookmarks!